# Change staus of downloadable product in magento after purchase?

Tags: product, downloadable

All products in my site are downloadable,

 I have uploaded the respective files while creating product.

But after purchase when user is redirected to his downloadable products, the link does not work and the status is pending.

The links only work if the status is set to complete via admin.

But I don't want this , user should be able to download the product after purchase,

Is their any way to set the default status of downloadable product to complete?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->Downloadable Product Options` and change the value for `Order Item Status to Enable Download` to `Pending`.